# Solve quadratic equation when coefficients may be 0

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I was given a problem to write a C program which would solve the equation **ax<sup>2</sup>+bx+c=0**, where **a**, **b** and **c** are coefficients with `double` type. Any of the coefficients may be zero. In this problem it is unclear to me how to handle the `double` variables.

Here is my code. As for now, I know that my program can't distinguish between two roots and infinitely many roots. It also doesn't detect the "linear equation situation". How can I make it detect an infinite number of solutions? I was also advised in the comments to calculate the root with the minus before the discriminant if b > 0 and then use the Viet's theorem. I understand that it is because it is always more accurate to sum two numbers. I also guess I should do the exact opposite with b < 0. But what if b == 0 ? In this case, the program will not do anything. Or should I just include b == 0 in b < 0 and have b <= 0 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    double a, b, c, x1, x2;

    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    scanf("%lf", &c); // just reading variables 
    //ax^2+bx+c=0
    if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0) {
        printf("no"); 
    } else {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a); //calculating roots 
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
        if ((fabs((a * x1 * x1 + b * x1 + c)) < DBL_EPSILON) & (fabs((a * x2 * x2 + b * x2 + c)) < DBL_EPSILON)) { //plugging the roots in
            if (fabs((x1 - x2)) < DBL_EPSILON) { //checking if the roots are equal
                printf("%lf", &x1); // if they are equal, we print only one of them
            } else {
                printf("%lf", &x1); // if they are not equal, we print both.
                printf("\n %lf", &x2);
            }
        } else { // if there are no two valid roots
            if ((fabs((a * x1 * x1 + b * x1 + c)) < DBL_EPSILON)) // we try to find one root.
                printf("%lf", &x1);
            if (fabs((a * x2 * x2 + b * x2 + c)) < DBL_EPSILON)
                printf("%lf", &x2);
            if ((fabs((a * x1 * x1 + b * x1 + c)) > DBL_EPSILON) & (fabs((a * x2 * x2 + b * x2 + c)) > DBL_EPSILON)) // if both of the plugged roots don't satisfy the equation
                printf("no");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solve quadratic equation when coefficients may be 0**

> How can I make it detect an infinite number of solutions?

When `a==0 && b == 0 && c == 0`.
No `DBL_EPSILON` needed really anywhere in this code.  See also [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174394/solve-quadratic-equation-when-coefficients-may-be-0/52189462#comment91316254_52177745).

> But what if b == 0 ?

```
if (b == 0) {  // y = a*x*x + c
  if (a) {
    double dd = -c/a;
    if (dd >= 0) {
      double d = sqrt(d);
      printf_roots("+/- roots", d,-d);
    } else {
      printf_roots("Complex roots", NAN, NAN);  // Note NAN may not exist
    }
  } else if (c) { // y = 0*x*x + c, c != 0
    printf_roots("No roots", NAN, NAN);
  } else { // y = 0*x + 0
    printf_roots("Infinite roots", -HUGE_VAL, HUGE_VAL);
  }
```

> Or should I just include b == 0 in b < 0 and have b <= 0 ?

Unless the coding goal requires a special output when `b==0`, I would only vector code on `b==0` as a subtest when `a==0` occurred.

```
if (a==0) {
  if (b == 0) {
```

---

The quadric equation, like much FP code, can readily overflow and hit 0, both cases losing all precision.

Consider the code below: the unnecessary subtraction may cause overflow or truncation to 0 versus the second which may not.  It is dependent on many things.

```
if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0)
// 
if (b * b < 4 * a * c)
```

Further, C allows various calculations to occur using wider math.  Research [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE_754_floating_point_support).  Because of this, to prevent `sqrt(value_less_than_0)`, code should calculate the [discriminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_2) and then test the object `x` that is going to be applied to `sqrt(x)`.

```
//if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0) {
//    printf("no"); 
//} else {
//    x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c))

double discriminate = b * b - 4 * a * c;
if (discriminate < 0) {
    printf("no"); 
} else {
    double d = sqrt(discriminate);  
    x1 = (-b + d)
```

---

As to the idea of "calculate the root with the minus before the discriminant if b > 0 and then use the Viet's theorem", I'd suggest for improved retained precision the below which does not subtract like signed values.

```
    double d = sqrt(discriminate);

    // Note x1*x2 = c/a
    if (b < 0) {
      x2 = (-b + d)/(2*a);
      x1 = c/a/x2;
    } else {
      x1 = (-b - d)/(2*a);
      x2 = c/a/x1;
    } 
    printf_roots("2 roots", x1, x2);
```

---

Notes on `printf("%lf", &x1);`.  You are not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Save time - enable them. Should be `printf("%lf", x1);`  No `&`.

Further `double` is *floating point*.  For FP code development use `"%e"`, `"%a"` or`"%g"` to full see significant information.

```
printf("%g\n", some_double);
// or better
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG -1, some_double);
```

Comment: `printf("%lf", &x1);` should really be `printf("%f", x1);` No `&`, nor `l`

Comment: @chqrlie Since C99 the `l` is OK and "has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier."

Answer (score 2):

Since division by zero is not allowed, you have to split the problem into 4 cases :

1. a != 0:
   this is case you treated in your code.
2. a == 0 && b != 0 :
   This is a linear equation where the solution is x = -c/b
3. a == 0 && b == 0 && c != 0 : There's no possible value for x.
4. In this last case, a, b and c are equals to 0 : there's infinitly many solutions for x.

EDIT: comparisons with epsilon removed since they seem to be useless

Comment: Comparing to `DBL_EPSILON` is inappropriate. `a`, b`, and `c` can be compared to zero with `== 0`; there is no “fuzziness” in comparison. And `DBL_EPSILON` is **huge** compared to values in the small end of the floating-point range; comparing to it produces false results for perfectly fine values of `a`, `b`, or `c` even when no error is present.

Comment: @AntoineMathys: x:=-b/2a is not a solution when Δ<0.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code:

- you should check the return values of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.
- you should use local variables for intermediary results to improve code readability
- your `printf` statements are incorrect: you should pass the values of the double variables instead of their addresses: `printf("%lf", &x1);` should read:

  ```
  printf("%f", x1);
  ```

Regarding the degenerate cases, you should just test those before trying to resolve the second degree equation.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double a, b, c, delta, x1, x2;

    if (scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (a == 0) {
        // not a quadratic equation
        if (b != 0) {
            printf("one solution: %g\n", -c / b);
        } else {
            if (c != 0) {
                printf("no solution\n");
            } else {
                printf("all real values are solutions\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

        if (delta < 0) {
            printf("no real solution\n");
        } else
        if (delta == 0) {
            printf("one double solution: %g\n", -b / (2 * a));
        } else {
            x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            printf("two solutions: %g, %g\n", x1, x2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```